# Traceback while trying to launch Presto

Tags: presto

I am trying to launch Presto by entering the following in the terminal:

```
sudo bin/launcher start
```

It shows me this:

```
Started as 16501 (This integer varies on every attempt)
```

Then, I tried to launch it by entering the following in terminal:

```
sudo bin/launcher run --verbose
```

The output I get is:

```
config_path     = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-             0.203/etc/config.properties
data_dir        = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203
etc_dir         = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/etc
install_path    = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203
jvm_config      = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/etc/jvm.config
launcher_config = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-  0.203/bin/launcher.properties
launcher_log    = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/var/log/launcher.log
log_levels      = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/etc/log.properties
log_levels_set  = False
node_config     = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/etc/node.properties
pid_file        = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/var/run/launcher.pid
properties      = {}
server_log      = /media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/var/log/server.log
verbose         = True

['java', '-cp', '/media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server- 0.203/lib/*', '-server', '-Xmx16G', '-XX:+UseG1GC',  '-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M', '-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit',  '-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent', '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError',  '-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError', '-Dconfig=/media/polly/161813A51813834/PrestoDB/presto-server-0.203/etc/config.properties',  'com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/launcher.py", line 445, in main
handle_command(command, o)
File "bin/launcher.py", line 329, in handle_command
run(process, options)
File "bin/launcher.py", line 251, in run
os.execvpe(args[0], args, env)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 355, in execvpe
_execvpe(file, args, env)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 382, in _execvpe
func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am unable to understand the error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the config.properties file:

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=3306
query.max-memory=2GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:3306
```

**EDIT**: After entering `sudo bin/launcher start` into the terminal and then `sudo bin/launcher status` , it says "Not running". Also there is no web page at localhost:3306. If it started successfully, then I should get a web page.

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` -- TL;DR: no `java` in `$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

Commands `sudo bin/launcher start` and `sudo bin/launcher run` conflicts with each other. First starts Presto in background while second starts Presto in foreground. You cannot start two Presto processes on the same machine because they try to allocate the same port (see your `config.properties` `http-server.http.port=3306`).

What did you want to achieve with `sudo bin/launcher run`? If you want to run a query then please use `presto-cli-*-executable.jar*`

Comment: I am using `sudo bin/launcher run` because the Presto docs say so (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html). Also after I execute the command  `sudo bin/launcher start` and then `sudo bin/launcher status`, it shows "Not running". If it had started successfully, then it should display a web page at localhost:3306. I am not getting the web page. There must be a problem somewhere. Web page should be like this (https://pallavisingh9.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/screenshot-from-2017-05-15-16-38-22.png?w=680)

Comment: Do you see `launcher.log` or `server.log`? Can you share their content?

Comment: Content of launcher.log is exactly the same as the output that I have posted above. Couldn't find server.log.

Comment: If you take a look at last log line: `['java', '-cp', '/media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server- 0.203/lib/*', '....',  'com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer']
`
Do you have java installed? See `/media/polly/161813A518138343/PrestoDB/presto-server- 0.203/lib/*'` is space `presto-server- 0.203` expected? Does this location (with space) exist?

Comment: The space isn't there in original logs. It has some how come here while trying to format. Also, I got it fixed, I have answered my own question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since I got it fixed myself, I will answer my own question for anyone who encounters this issue in future and comes across this question.

**Where exactly was the problem**: JRE. (Thanks to [kokosing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217852/kokosing) for pointing out that there might be some problem with java)

**What I did before**: I downloaded `jre-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz` from https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml, placed it in a partition or "media" different from where ubuntu is installed. I configured the .bashrc myself and added the following lines:

```
JAVA_HOME=/media/polly/161813A518138343/Java/jdk-10.0.1
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

For changes to take place, I executed `exec bash` in terminal.
To check if it was running I tried `java -version` and it displayed the version of java running. 
I tried to launch Presto, it wouldn't run.

**What I did after**: I removed the part that I had added to .bashrc. 
I used the command `sudo apt-get install default-jre`. After successful installation I entered `java -version` and it showed me the version of java installed and running. I tried to launch presto and it ran successfully. I am able to see the page at localhost:3360.